# How to create a background that each row has a border even when there is no data?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border

[image]

Please take a look at image above.

I want my xaml page background to be as such. Each and every row should always have border. I've already achieved the objective using itemControl and dump a dummy list. Although I get what I want, but it looks redundant so I'm trying to see if there is better way of doing it. Please don't suggest me to create an image that looks as such and use it as background.

Below is what I did:

```
<ItemControl DataContext="{Binding [someViewmodel]}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#E6E6E6"
    ItemSource="{Binding DummyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTempalte>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E6E6E6" Background="White">
                <StackPanel Height="50">
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemControl>
```

In my viewmodel:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
     Object haha = new Object();
     this.DummyList.add(haha);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT again:
If it is just a background you could add lines based on height of the screen, and add a line for every x pixels in the codebehind. If you want something on the lines use the datatemplate of items control of your choice like you did. And, of course create your own control for that so you don't mangle the codebehind of a page :)

If you can live with using an image use a vector image so the lines are nice and crisp and background transparent. Either crop the image to the screen size, crop the overflow, or place the image in a ViewBox and let it stretch to the size of the screen. There are many options, it really depends on what you and need.

EDIT:
Anoyher way is to draw the lines manually (if you use the grid). Abstract this to your own control

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Line Grid.Row="1" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="1" Y2="0" Stroke="DarkSlateBlue" StrokeThickness="3" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="2" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="1" Y2="0" Stroke="DarkSlateBlue" StrokeThickness="3" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="3" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="1" Y2="0" Stroke="DarkSlateBlue" StrokeThickness="3" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

I assume you want to use a grid since you said rows? Here is how you do it with the grid, simple set ShowGridLines to true. (notice dashed lines)

Code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: From the docs:

"Enabling grid lines creates dotted lines around all the elements within a Grid. Only dotted lines are available because this property is intended as a design tool to debug layout problems and is not intended for use in production quality code. If you want lines inside a Grid, style the elements within the Grid to have borders. "

Comment: Good to know there is such property but seems like it doesn't really fit

Comment: A seond option added.

Comment: This only works if you know exactly how many lines you wanna hardcode. My application may have to run on different screen resolutions

Comment: Hence why I wrote abstract this to your own control.

Comment: Because I'm still very new to WPF and hence trying to find out if there is any other better solution. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: If it is *just* a background you could add lines based on height of the screen, and add a line for every x pixels in the codebehind. If you want something *on* the lines use the datatemplate of items control of your choice like you did. The question isn't very clear, and its frustrating trying to 'guess' what you want.

Comment: And, of course create your own control for that so you don't mangle the codebehind of a *page* :) If you can live with using an image use a vector image so the lines are nice and crisp and background transparent. Eitehr crop the image to the screen size, crop the overflow, or place the image in a ViewBox and let it stretch to the size of the screen. There are many options, it really depends on what you and need.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to *not* draw all four sides of your `Border`. You can do that by adjusting the [`Border.BorderThickness` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.borderthickness%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try this instead:

```
<ItemControl DataContext="{Binding [someViewmodel]}" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" 
    BorderBrush="#E6E6E6"
    ItemSource="{Binding DummyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTempalte>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#E6E6E6" Background="White">
                <StackPanel Height="50">
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemControl>
```

If you want the lines to extend further, then just add some empty items to your data bound collection.

If I have misunderstood your problem (quite possible as your question is not clear), then please let me know *in detail*... *it looks redundant so I'm trying to see if there is better way of doing it* is *not* very descriptive an will *not* help anyone to understand your problem.